# Rx.Net Window function extension to support count, time AND size

Tags: c#, observable, reactive, rx.net

Actually I have an `IObservable<byte[]>` and want to window it not only on arrays count and time frame but also on the overall size of arrays passed the current window.

Please provide me with these techniques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom `Window` operator that attempts to replicate the functionality of the built-in `Window` overload that accepts `timeSpan` and `count` arguments, while also supporting the windowing by overall size.

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<TSource>> Window<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan timeSpan, int count,
    int size, Func<TSource, int> sizeSelector, IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (timeSpan < TimeSpan.Zero && timeSpan != Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeSpan));
    if (count < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
    if (size < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));
    if (sizeSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sizeSelector));
    scheduler = scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default;

    return Observable.Create<IObservable<TSource>>(observer =>
    {
        Subject<TSource> currentSubject = null;
        IStopwatch stopwatch = null;
        int itemCounter = 0;
        int currentSize = 0;

        return source.Subscribe(item =>
        {
            if (currentSubject == null)
            {
                currentSubject = new Subject<TSource>();
                observer.OnNext(currentSubject);
            }
            if (stopwatch == null && timeSpan != Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)
            {
                stopwatch = scheduler.StartStopwatch();
            }

            currentSubject.OnNext(item);
            itemCounter++;
            currentSize += sizeSelector(item);

            if (itemCounter == count
                || (stopwatch != null && stopwatch.Elapsed >= timeSpan)
                || currentSize >= size)
            {
                currentSubject.OnCompleted();
                currentSubject = null;
                if (stopwatch != null) stopwatch = scheduler.StartStopwatch();
                itemCounter = 0;
                currentSize = 0;
            }
        }, ex =>
        {
            if (currentSubject != null) currentSubject.OnError(ex);
            observer.OnError(ex);
        }, () =>
        {
            if (currentSubject != null) currentSubject.OnCompleted();
            observer.OnCompleted();
        });
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
observable.Window(timeSpan: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), count: 10,
    size: 100, sizeSelector: x => x.Length);
```

A new window is created every time the current window is full, or the given amount of time has elapsed, or the accumulated size becomes larger than the given size. The timer is restarted every time a window is emitted.

Comment: Added support for a user-defined `IScheduler`, for measuring the `timeSpan` duration.